# How to check jdbc version and jsp version?

Tags: jsp, jdbc

How to check jdbc version and jsp version?

I didn't get any solution till now from anywhere. I searched a lot about it but didn't got the solution.
Actually i made project in maven with technologies such as jdbc ,jsp ,servlet,mail api, log4j i did all but can't able to find version of jdbc.
Please answer if someone knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC is part of the Java runtime environment. If you use Java 8, it is JDBC 4.2, if you use Java 9 or higher, it is JDBC 4.3.

Unless you're talking about the version of your JDBC **driver**, then you should look at your Maven or Gradle definition of the dependency to find out its version.